# sublime text when open browser unicodeEncodeError

Tags: python, sublimetext3

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Applications/Sublime 
Text.app/Contents/MacOS/sublime_plugin.py", line 818, in run_
return self.run(edit)
File "open_in_browser in /Applications/Sublime 
Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages/Default.sublime-package", line 9, in run
File "./python3.3/webbrowser.py", line 70, in open_new_tab
File "./python3.3/webbrowser.py", line 62, in open
File "./python3.3/webbrowser.py", line 635, in open
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position  
56-57: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can i  fix this? I use the plugin SidebarEnhancements to open my html,but I  meet this problem.

Comment: please, provide code sample which raises error

Comment: I just add a plugin in sublime text3 named SidebarEnhancements ,and I use the keymap to open the html file in browser ,and then raise me a error.